# How can I send an email from powershell to an email address containing an Accent?

Tags: .net, email, powershell, encoding, character-encoding

I use the below code snippet to send HTML formatted email from powershell. This has been working without issue for some time until a group of foreign users was added to our environment, some of these new users have email addresses containing characters with accents (á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ). What can be done to handle addresses with these special characters?

I receive the following error when sending to send to an email address containg a ú:

```
Send-HTMLFormattedEmail -to 'thisütest@domain.com' -From sender@domain.com -Subject "testemail" -XSLPath "$scriptDir\emailbodyGen.xsl"`
-Days "1" -Company 'testcompany' -Relay email.domain.com -ToDisName "Tim" -FromDisName "sender" -LogoPath "$scriptDir\logo.gif"
```

**Error:**

Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The client or server is only configured for E-mail addresses with ASCII 
local-parts: thisütest@domain.com."
At C:\test\Untitled1.ps1:150 char:9
+         $Client.Send($Message)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

**Code:**

```
function Send-HTMLFormattedEmail {
    <# 
    .Synopsis
        Used to send an HTML Formatted Email.
    .Description
        Used to send an HTML Formatted Email that is based on an XSLT template.
    .Parameter To
        Email address or addresses for whom the message is being sent to.
        Addresses should be seperated using ;.
    .Parameter ToDisName
        Display name for whom the message is being sent to.
    .Parameter CC
        Email address if you want CC a recipient.
        Addresses should be seperated using ;.
    .Parameter BCC
        Email address if you want BCC a recipient.
        Addresses should be seperated using ;.
    .Parameter From
        Email address for whom the message comes from.
    .Parameter FromDisName
        Display name for whom the message comes from.
    .Parameter Subject
        The subject of the email address.
    .Parameter Days
        The number of days in which the passowrd will expire.
    .Parameter Company
        The Company name for this notification.
    .Parameter Relay
        FQDN or IP of the SMTP relay to send the message to.
    .Parameter XSLPath
        The full path to the XSL template that is to be used.
    .Parameter LogoPath
        The full path to the jpg image for the signature.
    .NOTES
        Taken from: http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1037-send-html-emails-via-powershell
    #>
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$To,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$ToDisName,
        [String]$CC,
        [String]$BCC,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$From,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$FromDisName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$Subject,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$Days,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$Company,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$Relay,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$XSLPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$LogoPath
        )

    try 
    {

        $Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

        # add the attachment, and set it to inline.
        $Attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($LogoPath)
        $Attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = $True
        $Attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "Inline"
        $Attachment.ContentType.MediaType = "image/gif"
        $Logo = "cid:logo" 

        # Load XSL Argument List
        $XSLArg = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
        $XSLArg.Clear() 
        $XSLArg.AddParam("To", $Null, $ToDisName)
        $XSLArg.AddParam("Days", $Null, $Days)
        $XSLArg.AddParam("Logo", $Null, $Logo)
        $XSLArg.AddParam("Company", $Null, $Company)

        # Load Documents
        $BaseXMLDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $BaseXMLDoc.LoadXml("<root/>")

        $XSLTrans = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
        $XSLTrans.Load($XSLPath)

        #Perform XSL Transform
        $FinalXMLDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $MemStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream

        $XMLWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($MemStream)
        $XSLTrans.Transform($BaseXMLDoc, $XSLArg, $XMLWriter)

        $XMLWriter.Flush()
        $MemStream.Position = 0

        # Load the results
        $FinalXMLDoc.Load($MemStream) 
        $Body = $FinalXMLDoc.Get_OuterXML()

        # Populate the Message.
        $html = [System.Net.Mail.AlternateView]::CreateAlternateViewFromString($body, $null, "text/html")
        $imageToSend = new-object system.net.mail.linkedresource($LogoPath,"image/jpg")
        $imageToSend.ContentID = "logo"
        $html.LinkedResources.Add($imageToSend)
        $message.AlternateViews.Add($html)
        $Message.Subject = $Subject
        $Message.IsBodyHTML = $True
        $message.Priority = 'High'

        # Add From
        $MessFrom = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $From, $FromDisName
        $Message.From = $MessFrom

        # Add To
        $To = $To.Split(";") # Make an array of addresses.
        $To | foreach {$Message.To.Add((New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailaddress $_.Trim()))} # Add them to the message object.

        # Add CC
        if ($CC){
            $CC = $CC.Split(";") # Make an array of addresses.
            $CC | foreach {$Message.CC.Add((New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailaddress $_.Trim()))} # Add them to the message object.
            }

        # Add BCC
        if ($BCC){
            $BCC = $BCC.Split(";") # Make an array of addresses.
            $BCC | foreach {$Message.BCC.Add((New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailaddress $_.Trim()))} # Add them to the message object.
            }

        # Create SMTP Client
        $Client = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $Relay

        # Send The Message
        $Client.Send($Message)
    }  
    catch 
    {
        throw $_
    }   
        $attachment.Dispose() #dispose or it'll lock the file
}

function Resolve-Error ($ErrorRecord=$Error[0])
{
   $ErrorRecord | Format-List * -Force
   $ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo |Format-List *
   $Exception = $ErrorRecord.Exception
   for ($i = 0; $Exception; $i++, ($Exception = $Exception.InnerException))
   {   "$i" * 80
       $Exception |Format-List * -Force
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmtpException: The client or server is only configured for e-mail addresses with ASCII local-parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260772/smtpexception-the-client-or-server-is-only-configured-for-e-mail-addresses-with)

Answer (score 0):

MailAddress has a ctor that allows you to specify the encoding, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f52hswkf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx